# What's the right way to remove an Ubuntu Unity web application?

Tags: unity, webapps

After I've tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge unity-webapps-googleplus` the application was not removed completely - say the state was not reverted to which it was before I have installed it. I can notice 2 effects: it is still present in the main menu (I have installed [an indicator](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-get-classic-start-menu-with-unity-launcher-ubuntu/) to display it) "others" section and the browser doesn't ask me to install it when I visit the site (even after I have manually removed it from `dontask-domains` and `allowed-domains` in `dconf`).

After I've tried dragging an Amazon icon to the trash can icon, the Amazon web application is still present in the main menu "others" section.

So how does one remove an Ubuntu Unity web application cleanly?

UPDATE:

```
dpkg -l | grep webapps
```

gives

```
ii  libunity-webapps0       2.5.0~daily13.03.18-0ubuntu1  i386  Web Apps integration with the Unity desktop
ii  unity-webapps-common    2.4.14-0ubuntu1               all   Unity WebApp integration scripts
ii  unity-webapps-service   2.5.0~daily13.03.18-0ubuntu1  i386  Service for Web Apps integration with the Unity desktop
```

Comment: probably the configuration files still there.
try:
`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`

Comment: Can you add the output of `dpkg -l | grep webapps`

Comment: Sure, @Mitch, already done.